# create files, with a template and a list of name and save on files

Tags: python

I have a list of fruits

> example:
>
> "banana",
>
> "apple",
>
> "grape",
>
> "strawberry"

and I want to create files 
with the text:

"This fruit is %fruit name%, its delicious"
and save as %fruit name%.fruits

how i do that? cam be in any language

Answer (score 1):

Read the Python tutorial -- more specifically, the section on reading and writing files: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files (but read the rest of the tutorial too! Python is awesome! :p ).

It should be pretty easy to apply that to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't recommend trying this in batch file.  Learning the basics of a scripting language such as Python or Perl is much better for this type of work.

Comment: if you can help me, how I could do that on python